# TypeError: reviews.reviewList.data is undefined in reactjs even when data is there

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the response from backed which looks something like this.
[image: imagedt]

But when i try to log the data like this.

```
render() {
    const { reviews } = this.props;
    console.log('rev', reviews.reviewList.data._embedded);
```

It gives me error saying this.

> TypeError: reviews.reviewList.data is undefined
>
> reviewDataReducer.jsx

```
const initialstate = {
  isFetching: false,
  reviewList: [],
  page: null,
  fetched: false,
  error: null
};

export default (state = initialstate, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_REVIEWS_LOAD:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_REVIEWS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetched: true,
        reviewList: action.payload
      };

    case actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_REVIEWS_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetched: false,
        isFetching: false,
        error: action.error
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

> reviewActions.jsx

```
export const getProductReviews = pid => dispatch => {
    console.log('rev pid',pid)
  dispatch({
    type: types.GET_PRODUCT_REVIEWS_LOAD
  });
  new _rest()
    .get(`/buyer/product/${pid}/review`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log("Review Action Response", res);
      dispatch({
        type: types.GET_PRODUCT_REVIEWS_SUCCESS,
        payload: res
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch({
        type: types.GET_PRODUCT_REVIEWS_ERROR,
        error: error
      });
    });
};
```

> connect

```
const mapStateToprops = state => ({
  reviews: state.reviews.data
});

const mapStateToDispatch = {
  getProductReviews
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToprops,
  mapStateToDispatch
)(ReviewContainer);
```

Comment: Can I see the full code? I couldn't find any problem here. The issue might be there on passing the props.

Comment: review is coming from redux state. when i try to `console.log(this.props.reviews.reviewList.data)` till here data returns fine but problem arise when i put `_embedded `here

Comment: @AlanPaulMathew i have updated my question can u please have a look.

Comment: ok. Got it. Can I see the redux - component connecting code (That connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(component_name)).

Because here in your component it is 'reviews' but in the redux, it is 'reviewList'.

Comment: I have updated the question have look @AlanPaulMathew

Comment: What is the reducer name? Here you are referring it as 'reviews'. Even though the 'reviews' reducer doesn't have a 'data' field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210523/discussion-between-alan-paul-mathew-and-aditya-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Your information is limited but I will try to be best.

1] Error is because you'r traversing object wrong not because data in not there in this case.
2] render() {
    const { reviews } = this.props;

Here I feel you mapping redux state to prop using (mapStateToProps) if so reducer is responsible how you set data in redux state.

Comment: I have updated my question have a look hope that may help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is there inside the mapStateToprops connection. Try to debug it there.

```
 const mapStateToprops = state => {
  debugger;
  return ({
    reviews: state.reviews.data
  });
};
```

Open your browser console and check the value of state;

Comment: yeah i can find the value of state

Comment: What is the value of state?